# File.mkdirs warning from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, warnings

in my app I create a new dir in this way;

```
File mydir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "/my_directory");
if (!mydir.exists()) {
    mydir.mkdirs();
}
```

and it works well, but Android Studio (0.8.9) just continues to report me this warning:

***Result of "File.mkdirs()" is ignored***

Anyone can explain me why? Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

because you dont do anything with what it returns, you just ignore it

ex.

```
if(mydir.mkdirs()){
    //do something
}else{
    //do something else
}
```

you dont need to do anything, its just a warning

Comment: it is nothing to worry about its only a warning

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring result of File.mkdir()

Read [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904329/warning-file-mkdir-is-ignored/#27904523) for more clerification