# WARNING: File.mkdir() is ignored

Tags: android, audio-recording, sd-card, android-sdcard

I've created a basic Audio Recording App using Media Recorder API's. I'm trying to create a folder in the SD card and to save my recorded files to that folder. I'm getting this warning with following code.

**File.mkdir() is ignored**

```
    // Assign random number to avoid audio file from overwriting
    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

    // Specify a Location for the recorded file to be stored in the SD card
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/AudioRecordTest/";
    File path = new File(mFileName);
    if(!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdir();
    }
    mFileName += "/AudioRecordTest_" + tsLong.toString() + ".mp3";
```

How to solve this warning message. Feel free to modify the code if there is any other mistake.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I expect that the (compilation) warning message really says this:

> Result of File.mkdir() is ignored

... or something like that.  It is telling you that you are ignoring the result of the `mkdir()` call that tells you whether or not a directory was created.

One way to avoid the warning would be to test the result and act appropriately.  Another would be to simply assign the result to a temporary variable, ignore it, and (potentially) crash later because the directory wasn't created when it should have been.

(Guess which solution is better ...)

---

> Feel free to modify the code if there is any other mistake.

Since you asked ... it is BAD STYLE to use Hungarian notation for Java variable names.  Java is a strongly typed language where all variables have a clear declared types.  You should not need the mental crutches of some ghastly identifier convention to tell you what a variable's type is intended to be.

Answer (score 16):

As *@Stephen C* suggests, i handled in these ways

1)

`boolean isDirectoryCreated= path.mkdir();`

and ignore 'isDirectoryCreated'

2)  (Recommended)

```
 boolean isDirectoryCreated=path.exists();
 if (!isDirectoryCreated) {
     isDirectoryCreated= path.mkdir();
 }
 if(isDirectoryCreated) {
    // do something
 }
```

3)

```
if (!path.exists()) {
   if(path.mkdir()){
     // do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore this warning, add this on the method:
@SuppressWarnings("all")

Answer (score 1):

I created a utility function:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static void IGNORE_RESULT(boolean b) {}
```

And then to use:

```
IGNORE_RESULT(path.mkdir());
```

I like this solution because it is self documenting.  You are explicitly stating that you know there is a result and you are intentionally ignoring it.  It should also optimize out to a NOP during compilation so there is no unnecessary test at runtime just to suppress a useless warning.